# Splitting a string in two parts

Tags: python, string, split

I want to split a string in two parts like this:

```
>>> label = ('A1')
['A', '1']
```

Is there any method to do this in python?

I tried:

```
>>> label = label.split(',')
['A1']
```

As you can see the comma is not printed.

Comment: string is iterable in python, you can just loop through it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list):

```
>>> label = 'A1'
>>> list(label)
['A', '1']
>>>
```

`list` will iterate over the string and collect its characters into a new list.

Also, you cannot use `str.split` here because the method was designed to split on characters/substrings and remove them from the resulting list.  For example, `'a b c'.split()` would split on whitespace and remove those characters from the returned list, which is `['a', 'b', 'c']`.  You however want to break the string up into individual characters while still keeping all of them.